# Quiz app in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building a quiz app in rails. I want to have it so that anyone can create a quiz. But I have different types of quiz questions they can choose to add. One would allow you to type in text the other is multiple choice.

My question is would I set up each different question type as it's own model e.g

*questionchoice*

*questiontext*

Or would it be better to have a model question which in turn has a type attribute.

Then when I render it on the page I say if type = "multiplechoice" then display this.

I'm new to rails so sorry for any inconvenience if this question seems stupid.

Any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: Since those different types of questions might require different handling of answers as well, I’d say they should be modeled as separate objects, inheriting from a common base question object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create 2 models:

- `Question` (id, name, text, question_type_id)
- `QuestionType` (id, name)

Then you can add different question types: text, radio button, checkbox.
And link to these types from `questions` table.